# Set Textview + Edittext + Button

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to put in the same row a TextView, and Edittext and a button but I am having the problem that the button is not aligned properly to left and in small screens edittext fills entire with.

Small screen:
[image]

Big Screen: [image]

My codification is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/address_textview"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address_edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/address_textview_hint"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/search_button"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/address_edittext"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/address_edittext"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Go" />
                </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, many people will tell you that `hint` is Android's solution for not needing the label. I don't care if you use the label or not but it does save you space, especially on smaller screens. That was just an FYI.

Now, your `RelativeLayout` that only has a `Button` appears to be useless...I would remove that. You can use `layout_weight` so that each `View` takes up the appropriate amount of space. Make sure to make the `layout_width="0dp"`. So it may look something like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/address_textview"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="@string/address_textview_hint"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/search_button"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/address_edittext"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/address_edittext"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Go" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I used 2,3,1 for the `weights` of your `TextView`, `EditText`, and `Button` respectively. You may need to change those to get exactly what you want but that should give you a start.

Answer (score 6):

Apply a weight to your EditText so it will take up as much room as it can while letting the other two elements do the normal wrap_content. To do this, remove the relative layout container and then change the EditText width to "0dp" and give it a layout_weight of "1" as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/address_textview"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/address_textview_hint"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/search_button"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/address_edittext"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/address_edittext"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Go" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @EvanB apart from using `weight`, this answer is completely different. Also, since they were only a minute apart, I think its safe to assume that petey was still writing his when yours was published since he was also writing complete code. Let's all be friends

Comment: Perfect. It was exactly what I want.

Comment: @codeMagic I think I intended to add "lol" to that, I'm not normally crass. Apologies.

Comment: @EvanB ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. The SO world is once again at peace with the universe

Answer (score 2):

Layout weigth is ideal for designing layouts that adjust to screen size. However, make sure to set layout_width to 0dp, or it won't work properly.

Use like this:

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean the button is not properly aligned to the right.

It's because your RelativeLayout's `android:width="wrap_content"`, but it should be `android:width="match_parent"`.

Also, you'd be better off setting your EditText's `android:width="0dp"` and adding `android:weight="1"` so that it expands/contracts between screen sizes.