# LinearLayout with Textview should overflow

Tags: android, textview

This is my current layout with `LinearLayout`, `TextViews` and `EditText`.

Text is dynamic. If it is getting long then the last `TextView` lumps to the right and expands. I would like to have it overflow to a new line like writing to a book. Is this possible with standard android possibilities? Or if not any library which can do this?

**layout file**

```
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_question_block"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_question_start"
                        style="@style/SessionDetailSectionHeader"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:text="asff" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_one"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:ems="3"
                        android:maxLength="5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_question_mid"
                        style="@style/SessionDetailSectionHeader"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"

                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:text="asfasdf" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text_two"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:ems="3"
                        android:maxLength="5" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_question_end"
                        style="@style/SessionDetailSectionHeader"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:text="asdfasdf asdfsdf fdgffd" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It certainly is possible. Post the layout file so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `width` of all of your `Views` set to `wrap_content` so, naturally, it will be as wide as it needs to be to hold the text.

You can use [weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) for each and set the `width` of each to `"0dp"`. The amount of `weight` will depend on how wide you want each to be.

You can see [this answer for an example of using weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868707/set-textview-edittext-button/19868792#19868792)

Comment: yes but i want to overflow to the next line if not matching one row. your link is discussing a single line layout

Comment: It will go to the next line as long as you don't have `maxLines` set

Comment: no its not. only the last text view has several lines. I want to continue the last word on the right to the left dont matter to what child element of linear layout it belongs.

Comment: If you could post some image of what you get and what you want, it would help. I'm a bit confused on what you have and what you want.

Comment: i cannot post pictures - not allowed for me yet

Comment: You can upload the pictures to http://imgur.com/ and edit your post with the link. Then a user with appropriate permissions can edit them into the post. You can ping me when you've done it and I can add them